# Nodport services are not accessable from master

Tags: kubernetes

We have k8s cluster of 3 nodes.
I can access the services via slaves public IP & NodePort. It works for every slave in spite of actual pod location. But for some reason it doesn't work for master.

The `kubectl get services --all-namespaces` on master node print the actual services list:

```
NAMESPACE  NAME    TYPE      CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP  PORT(S)         AGE
xxx        kibana  NodePort  10.100.214.218  <none>       5601:30141/TCP  1d
```

How can I enable such routing for master node?

Kubernetes version: v1.8.6

Infrastructure related output of `kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces`:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE  IP              NODE
kube-system   etcd-k8s-master                       1/1       Running   9          2d   172.20.41.199   k8s-master
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-master             1/1       Running   1          2d   172.20.41.199   k8s-master
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-master    1/1       Running   1          2d   172.20.41.199   k8s-master
kube-system   kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-2fq94             3/3       Running   0          2d   10.36.0.14      k8s-slave2
kube-system   kube-proxy-dhsl9                      1/1       Running   1          2d   172.20.41.199   k8s-master
kube-system   kube-proxy-mkjzn                      1/1       Running   0          2d   172.20.41.194   k8s-slave1
kube-system   kube-proxy-stjm6                      1/1       Running   1          2d   172.20.41.195   k8s-slave2
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-master             1/1       Running   9          2d   172.20.41.199   k8s-master
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-747d579ff5-qp7rh 1/1       Running   2          2d   10.32.0.2       k8s-master
kube-system   weave-net-n8n64                       2/2       Running   0          2d   172.20.41.194   k8s-slave1
kube-system   weave-net-vh6ng                       2/2       Running   1          2d   172.20.41.195   k8s-slave2
kube-system   weave-net-w9mn8                       2/2       Running   2          2d   172.20.41.199   k8s-master
```

Comment: Do you have kube-proxy running on your masters? It is kube-proxy which is responsible for making the NodePort available.

Comment: hi @starseed. looks like kube-proxy is running on master node. I've updated the question.